# Dataset vs Schema Definition

Tags: google-bigquery, dataset, schema

When GCP introduces the term 'dataset', it sounds like the definition of 'schema' in rdbs while gcp considers schemas as data types. Are you guys getting this perception as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the mapping is:

- Project - catalog
- Dataset - schema

This is the convention used in BigQuery's [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro) as well.